# Golang Bun select with group by

Tags: go

I am trying to use Bun in Golang to create a select query, which groups over a state variable and simply counts the elements for each state.

The raw sql quey looks like this:

```sql
SELECT state, count(*) FROM "jobs" AS "j" GROUP BY "state"
```

If I quey the database manually by executing this query, i get the following result:

```
state,count
2,1
1,1
```

This is exactly as i expect the output to be.

The Go Bun code looks like this:

```golang
func FindJobGroups(db *bun.DB, ctx context.Context) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    err := db.NewSelect().Model((*Job)(nil)).ColumnExpr("state, count(*)").Group("state").Scan(ctx, &m)
    return m, err
}
```

The generated SQL statement (debug) looks exactly as expected:

```
[bun]  16:18:59.626   SELECT                  592µs  SELECT state, count(*) FROM "jobs" AS "j" GROUP BY "state"
```

But the result object `m` only contains the count for the first state:

```
1 = count -> 1
0 = state -> 2
```

The second state is simply ignored / not contained in the result object.

Is there any way with Bun to perform this query and get the result I am observing in pure SQL?

---

Additional details:

Job definition:

```golang
type Job struct {
    bun.BaseModel `bun:"table:jobs,alias:j"`
    ID            int64            `bun:",pk,autoincrement"`
    State         int64            `json:"state"`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
func FindJobGroups(db *bun.DB, ctx context.Context) ([]map[string]interface{}, error) {
    var m []map[string]interface{}
    err := db.NewSelect().Model((*Job)(nil)).ColumnExpr("state, count(*)").Group("state").Scan(ctx, &m)
    return m, err
}
```

As you need multiple results, so the result destination variable should be a slice.

The result will be like

```
[
 map[state:2 count:1] 
 map[state:1 count:1]
]
```